# When using JS by using the allowJs option in Typescript, how can I use object properties as optional?

Tags: typescript

```
// hello.js
export const hello = ({ msg }) => {
    if (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
};
```

I tried to use the above JS file that defines the hello function in typescript.

```
// app.ts
import { hello } from './hello';
hello({}); // occurs ts error
```

I was expecting it to run without error, but I'm getting ts error.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

I can't change the code of `js` file, so I want to respond only through some `ts` settings.

Comment: Oops, I'm really sorry, I deleted someone's comment by mistake!!!